# RGB value not change correctly after saving image in JAVA

Tags: java, image, rgb, bufferedimage

I'm trying to read an Image type JPG/JPEG to `BufferedImage` , change RGB value of pixel (0,0)
Image file : http://i.upanh.com/rcfutp 
but it didn't work correctly
Here is what i've try
Read image

```
public BufferedImage readImage1(String path)
    {
        BufferedImage _image = null;
        BufferedImage copy = null;
        try {
            _image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            copy = new BufferedImage(_image.getWidth(), _image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            copy.getGraphics().drawImage(_image, 0, 0, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return copy;
    }
```

Write Image

```
public void writeImage1(String path,BufferedImage _image)
    {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(_image, "jpg", new File(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client Code

```
    BufferedImage image = readImage1("E:/2.jpg");
System.out.print((image.getRGB(0, 0))&0xFFFFFF);
System.out.print("-");
image.setRGB(0, 0, 0x00000F);
System.out.print((image.getRGB(0, 0))&0xFFFFFF);
System.out.print("-");
writeImage1("E:/3.jpg", image);     
image = readImage1("E:/3.jpg");
System.out.print((image.getRGB(0, 0))&0xFFFFFF);
```

System.out.print return

```
7736127-15-5439516
```

I hope it was `7736127-15-15`,but it return `7736127-15-5439516`
please help me to correct ,thank you very much guy

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: updated sir, thank you, i m not good at English, nice to wait for your help, i've worked on this for 2 weeks, very tired...

Comment: @user1747373 I had a similar issue when I was working on image manipulation. I was not using JAVA but ended up having similar issues. I eventually figured out that it had to do with how JPEGs are compressed when saving them.

Comment: *"nice to wait for your help"*  It is good you like it, but I am still waiting to see an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible because of how jpg compresses data, when you are operating on every pixel of the image it is the unpacked version of the image you are operating on, the jpg format is a lossy compression format. Compressing an image then decompressing it will not yield the original image. This is why pixel values are different.

This can be clearly seen in the following image. Notice the "lines" to the right, the right side is the jpg compression then decompression of the left side.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.beans.Transient;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageTest extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private BufferedImage saved;

    public ImageTest(int w, int h) {
        image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        randomizeImage(image);
        saveAndLoadImage();
        saveResultToLossLess();
    }

    private void saveResultToLossLess() {
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth() * 2,
                image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        result.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        result.getGraphics().drawImage(saved, image.getWidth(), 0, null);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(result, "png", new File("comparison.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void randomizeImage(BufferedImage image) {
        // Draw a blue gradient, note that in the array below
        // pixels[i] = blue, pixels[i+1] = green, pixels[i+2] = red
        byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                .getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 3) {
            pixels[i] = (byte) (255.0 * i / pixels.length);
            pixels[i + 1] = (byte) (128.0 * i / pixels.length);
            pixels[i + 2] = (byte) (64.0 * i / pixels.length);
        }
    }

    private void saveAndLoadImage() {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            saved = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        if (saved != null)
            g.drawImage(saved, image.getWidth(), 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth() * 2, image.getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageTest test = new ImageTest(600, 600);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(test);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: SO resizes the image, in chrome rightclick the image and open in new tab.

Comment: ok now i've got it sir :D thanks so much. This means no way to do it with JPG/JPEG file?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Comment: You can still use a jpeg to hide data, that is fully possible but I suggest you open another question and ask specifically for help with what you are trying to achieve not with what you are trying to do to try and achieve that. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: GOod luck with your project

Comment: Thanksso much for your help ^^